# Why did the government of Russia bother to recognize the breakaway areas if it is going to invade Ukraine today?

Tags: ukraine

Why did the government of Russia bother to recognize the breakaway areas if they are going to invade Ukraine today? The predictions of an invasion seem to be of a much larger area - as far as Kiev, so it would include these areas.

Comment: Maybe he is only going to invade the part he has recognized?

Comment: Only Putin himself knows that.

Comment: 'Cause then it isn't an invasion, it's just a state visit to some newly created independent countries?

Comment: Because he is going to send in "Peace Keeping" forces? From what I am hearing that is exactly what he is doing

Comment: Your answer is probably that your question makes a lot of firm assumptions about Putin's plans, which still really aren't that clear

Answer (score 6):

The Crimea made an (internationally not recognized) [independence declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annexation_of_Crimea_by_the_Russian_Federation#Legal_issues) before the (internationally not recognized) referendum followed by the (internationally not recognized) accession of the (briefly) 'independent' Crimea into Russia.

So Russia seems to believe that this piecemeal course of action has less resistance than the outright annexation a foreign country.

It would also be more in line with the typical size of a Russian [Oblast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_divisions_of_Russia).